# How to display specific error message using Java web.xml?

Tags: java

New to Java, so ...

Right now the call stack is like this, (there could be details missing, but these are basic steps)

1. In prehandle of the http request in java, if the authentication information is wrong say wrong password from UI, we send `403` back

```
 response.sendError(403);
```

2. web.xml has this

```
   <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error/forbidden</location>
    </error-page>
```

3. ErrorController.java mapps /error/forbidden to

```
    new ModelAndView("errorPage");
```

4. errorPage.jsp will display static error messages to user.

Now at step 1, we have function can append detailed error message for the http response

```
sendErrorInResponse(response, errorMessage);
```

basically we send back specific error message with `403`.

My Question is, how to pass this specific error message to the `errorPage.jsp` for display ?

Comment: If you're new to Java, the first thing to be aware of is that `web.xml` configuration is legacy. Modern Java Web applications (Spring Boot, Micronaut, Dropwizard) use Web servers that are configured by the tools instead of the "external deployment" model.

Comment: you are right, our existing code base in on Java 1.8, so i'm still using old stuff ...

Comment: "web.xml configuration is legacy." since when? Sure you could use a framework if you like and last I checked web.xml is still part of Servlet 4.

Comment: Probably he thinks that since he do not write web.xml, it is deprecated XDD. Maybe someday, but for the moment all those tools does the work for you (including create web.xml and many other trash).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like the following in `errorPage.jsp`:

```
The error code is <%=response.getStatus() %><br>
Error message: <%=exception.getMessage() %>
```

Comment: the 1st line response.getStatus() dos work, but not the 2nd line, "exception" cannot be resolved in my errorPage.jsp. Any suggestions ?

Comment: i did this: myHttpServletResponse.sendError(403, "my msg"). So in jsp file, which method to use to get "my msg" pls ?

Answer (score 1):

Where you do:

```
new ModelAndView("errorPage");
```

Change into:

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("errorPage");
String yourCustomErrorMessage = "This is a test";
model.addObject("msg", yourCustomErrorMessage);
```

Then replace yourCustomErrorMessage with the value you want.

In the JSP use ${msg} directly in the html code. Something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>HTTP 403 Forbidden</h1>
    <h2>${msg}</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.